# How do I clear Session in within OnTokenValidated in .NET Core 6

Tags: .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, .net-6.0, asp.net-authorization

How can I clear the Session inside OnTokenValidated after a user logs in?  Here's my Program.cs code (.NET Core 6):

```
builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {

            // check database, set claims etc. ....

            ctx.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
         
        }
    };
});
```

... ctx.HttpContext.Session.Clear() doesn't work.

When I check ctx.HttpContext.Session.GetString("SomeSessionVar") it's null here, but in my razor page, the session variables are back from the previous login.

Comment: try Session.Contents.RemoveAll()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there is no "Contents" property on ctx.HttpContext.Session, or a RemoveAll() on ctx.HttpContext.Session either

Comment: I am curious if this also.